# Elements are identifying successfully but while sending keys getting no such element error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Elements are identifying successfully but while sending keys getting no such element error.

Assert.assertTrue() used for element presence.

Comment: http://vdc01dlap0335:8080/tasks/add_new_tasks.do?resetForm=true&popupMode=true&customerId=-1&projectId=-1&userId=1

Comment: using above page for Task Name text field

Comment: Please share the code you are using and the HTML you are working with in your question. Otherwise there is not much we can do to help.

Comment: <input class="text" type="text" title="" style="" onfocus="focusTaskName(this, 0)" onblur="checkTaskName(this, 0)" 
value="" tabindex="11" size="73" maxlength="255" name="task[0].name"/>

Comment: I used name attribute for XPATH.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant HTML and the code you are using.

Answer (score -2):

Example of using pageObjects to grab elements:

```
public class Grabber {
    /*
     *      There exists a plugin in firefox to right click an element, inspect it, then right clicking the element
     *      and copying the xpath and pasting it here.
     */

    private static WebElement element = null;

    public static WebElement input_box(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPATH HERE")));
        //Used if element is a button or needs to bet clicked
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("XPATH HERE")));
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH HERE"));
        return element;
    }

}
```

How to use it :

EDIT: Initialize, NavigateTo, and Dispose will give you an error since they must be static, I wrote this quickly to give an example and you should edit it as you see fit to get what you want working. I hope I pointed you the right direction to solving your problem.

EDIT: The dispose here is to get rid of the driver when it is complete or an exception has been thrown. To remove the Temp files that are left out.

```
public class Test {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private WebDriverWait wait;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            initialize();
            navigateTo("www.somewhere.com");
            Grabber.input_box(driver, wait).sendKeys("I want to send these keys");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            dispose();
        }

    }

    private void initialize() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    }

    private void navigateTo(String url) {
        driver.get(url);
    }

    private void dispose() {
        RemoteWebDriver cRDriver = (RemoteWebDriver) driver;
        while (cRDriver.getSessionId() != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. This isn't a proper page object either.

Comment: Please show me an example of a proper page object so I may learn aswell.

Comment: @JeffC I would like an example of a proper page object