# Clickin the relevant button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have page where a number of products are displayed and I need to find a way of `clicking` the relevant `buttons` for the chosen product (the name of the product is fed from data sheet). Each product's details are stored in a `div class="cf"`

```
<div class="cf">
   <div class="component ticket-item-base ticket-item-options cf">
      <div class="ticket-image">
         <picture>
            <span class="alt-text">City 7 day megarider</span>
      </div>
      <div class="ticket-item-details">
         <h3>City 7 day megarider</h3>
         <ul>
            <li class="icon ticket-calendar">Unlimited travel X76 service.</li>
            <li class="icon ticket-location">
               <li class="icon ticket-person">1 adult</li>
               <li class="icon ticket-discount">Save when you buy online</li>
               <li class="terms">
                  <a class="open-popup" href="#ticket-item-terms-popup-0-9">Full terms & conditions for this ticket</a>
               </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="ticket-fulfilment-price">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="ticket-option">
               <div class="ticket-price-panel">
                  <label>Total</label>
                  <div class="ticket-price">
                     <div class="button-cart-wrapper cf">
                        <a class="submit-btn uniform-button button-orange button-smaller button-cart" data-ticket-id="7b0c3c08-a82a-4421-8232-dbb15def3428" href="#">
                           <span class="js-info-pop-up">Add to basket</span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="component added-to-basket-pop-up info-pop-up cf" style="display: block;">
                           <a class="close-icon" href="#">
                              <span class="alt-text">Close</span>
                           </a>
                           <p>
                              <span>1 ticket</span> added to basket.
                           </p>
                           <a class="link-arrow" href="/basket">View basket</a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="more-details-panel">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="more-details-panel">
                     </div>
                     <div id="ticket-item-terms-popup-0-9" class="overlay white-popup mfp-hide zoom-anim-dialog rich-text cf">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
```

Below are the steps on how I'm tackling it:

1. Getting the name of the product.
2. Checking if the product is sold on-line, then clicking on its relevant button. The buttons I want to click on once the product is found are: Add to Basket and Close Icon.

The latest code:

```
// List products that have class-cf
List<WebElement> listProduct = driver.findElements(By.xpath(
        "//html/body/div/div[4]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[@class='accordion-content cf']/div[@class='cf']"));

for (WebElement eachElem : listProduct)
{
    System.out.println("Searching for the exact element:");

    if (eachElem.getText().contains(TicketName))
    {
        // Identify the button to click on
        WebElement button = eachElem.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@class='js-info-pop-up']"));

        // WebElement button = eachElem.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div/div[1]/div/div/a/span[contains(text(),'Add to basket')]"));

        Thread.sleep(500);
        break; // Break out of iteration.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any errors you are getting?

Comment: No errors - but not getting the relevant buttons clicked (i.e. Add Basket and Close-icon) for the chosen product.

Comment: Did you try to use xpath to find "a" element which contains Add to basket? Btw this findElement find ALL elements where is Add to basket, try to create a custom xpath

Comment: @AzMar I'm assuming the Add to basket `span` is inside the `a` above it?

Comment: @Hrabosch,, thanks but that's why I'm here: any suggestion on how this xpath expression looks like...:).

Comment: @Hrabosch or anyone, please check the code above - Have I missed something for the button not clicked?.

Comment: Please clean up your question. We only need the relevant HTML and your most recent code attempt with the corresponding errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your site... :)

The way I generally approach tasks like this is to grab an outer element that contains all the stuff I care about for each item. In this case, as you mentioned, we're looking for a `div class="cf"`. Once I get that "container" element, I start looking for the child elements that I care about. In this case, the two `h3` tags for the ticket name and the purchase location. Once I compare the ticket name to the ticket name I'm looking for and make sure that the purchase location is online, I click the Add to basket link and the close button (both are still children).

Below is working code. You may need to add a wait at the beginning. The site seems to be slow at times and sometimes the search would start before the first few items were completely loaded for some reason. I'll leave that to you to figure out.

```
driver.get("https://www.stagecoachbus.com/regionaltickets/yorkshire/rotherham/megarider");

// close the Please set your location popup
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#location-overlay > a.close-icon.js-close-overlay")).click();

String desiredTicketName = "22X 7 day megarider"; // read this from sheet
System.out.println("Looking for: " + desiredTicketName);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
List<WebElement> ticketContainers = wait
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div[class='cf']")));
for (WebElement ticketContainer : ticketContainers)
{
    List<WebElement> h3s = ticketContainer.findElements(By.tagName("h3"));
    String currentTicketName = h3s.get(0).getText();
    String currentPurchaseLocation = h3s.get(1).getText();
    if (currentTicketName.contains(desiredTicketName) && currentPurchaseLocation.contains("Smart - online"))
    {
        // found the ticket and it's sold online

        // click Add to basket
        ticketContainer.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.submit-btn")).click();

        // click Close
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy(ticketContainer, By.cssSelector("a.close-icon"))).get(0)
                .click();

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the piece of code. It has really improved the speed of looking for element...:). One more question, I need to count the number of products for each card number. I used this code but not the getting wright count:  List<WebElement> labels= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[@class='ticket-type']"));  int ProdNum = labels.size();

Comment: Sure. Can you put this in a new question and add some more details? I'm not sure what you are trying to count. What's the card number? I tried finding that element you provided the XPath for and couldn't find any element with the ticket-type class so I'm not sure if we're on the same page or ? Just put all these details in the new question and label it with the same tags and I'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a method which I find more useful to use.
I personally perfer using xpath this way as I find it more accurate, but it really is just personal preference maybe. You could give it a try if it helps.

[Elements are identifying successfully but while sending keys getting no such element error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874942/elements-are-identifying-successfully-but-while-sending-keys-getting-no-such-ele)

Example of using pageObjects to grab elements:

```
public class Grabber {
    /*
     *      There exists a plugin in firefox to right click an element, inspect it, then right clicking the element
     *      and copying the xpath and pasting it here.
     */

    private static WebElement element = null;

    public static WebElement input_box(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("XPATH HERE")));
        //Used if element is a button or needs to bet clicked
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("XPATH HERE")));
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH HERE"));
        return element;
    }

}
```

How to use it :

EDIT: Initialize, NavigateTo, and Dispose will give you an error since they must be static, I wrote this quickly to give an example and you should edit it as you see fit to get what you want working. I hope I pointed you the right direction to solving your problem.

EDIT: The dispose here is to get rid of the driver when it is complete or an exception has been thrown. To remove the Temp files that are left out.

```
public class Test {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private WebDriverWait wait;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            initialize();
            navigateTo("www.somewhere.com");
            Grabber.input_box(driver, wait).sendKeys("I want to send these keys");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            dispose();
        }

    }

    private void initialize() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    }

    private void navigateTo(String url) {
        driver.get(url);
    }

    private void dispose() {
        RemoteWebDriver cRDriver = (RemoteWebDriver) driver;
        while (cRDriver.getSessionId() != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.This will work because 'Add to basket' is not a class.It is the text inside the span.

```
WebElement button = eachElem.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Add to basket')]"));   
button.click(); 
Thread.Sleep(2000); 
eachElem.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Close')]")‌​).Click()
```

Comment: it did click on the first button and not the button that's related to the product name TicketName?.

Comment: can u please tell which element u want to click in the html clearly

Comment: if it is a pop-up window you can use driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

Comment: There are two buttons i want to click on  Add to basket, then close-icon

Comment: After clicking Add to basket what is happening in the page.is any pop-up displayed or any new window is getting opened?

Comment: little window which for close-icon button  to be clicked.

Comment: You can use this code after clicking on Add to basket button. eachElem.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Close')]")).Click();

Comment: WebElement button = eachElem.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Add to basket')]"));  Thread.Sleep(2000); 
button.click();eachElem.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Close')]")).Click()

Comment: the button got clicked but not for the correct product?.

Comment: which button is getting clicked for wrong product? was there many 'Add to basket' buttons in the page?

Comment: In the html you have shown what is the data you are getting from excel? 'City 7 day megarider' is this the data you are taking from excel

Comment: Both buttons - If the correct product is found (which in this case TicketName, then the relevant buttons (i.e. Add to basket and close-icon) should be clicked.

Comment: Yes - It is a variable so there are other products on the same page - depending on the name of the product, the relevant buttons should be identified and clicked.

Comment: Is there a way I could show/send u a screen shot in here?

Comment: Other products are in <div class="cf"> and all are on the same page.

Comment: please see ur email

Comment: WebElement button = eachElem.findElement(By.xpath("//div[descendant::h3[text()='your product name']]/following::div/div/div[1]/div/div/a/span[contains(text(),'Add to basket')]]"));

Comment: first check if this is working for clicking on add to basket for ur required product by replacing 'your product name' with the name of the product

Comment: By.xpath("//div[descendant::h3[text()='youe product name']]/following::div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/a/span[contains(text(),'close')]]")                                         this is for clicking on close

Comment: @Sai- both of them didn't work  and i got no errors.

Comment: I guess both need to be placed inside the IF condition?. right?

Comment: ya u can put in if condition and check the xpath given as in html document or not once again.replacr 'your product name' with "+tmp+"

Comment: check the case sensitivity of button names

Comment: or anyone who uses Selenium-webdriver, I'm getting no where with resolving this. Does anyone got better solution?.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(WebElement eachElem:listProduct)
{
            String tmp = eachElem.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(.,'" + TicketName + "')]")).getText();    
            System.out.println("Name of the product: " + tmp);
            if (tmp.equals(TicketName)){ 
                System.out.println("Inside the IF loop");
                //Get the parent of the Element <h3></h3> to fetch the child span
                WebElement parentEle = eachElem.findElement(By.xpath("../../..")); 
                WebElement button = parentEle.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Add to basket')]"));   
                 button.click(); //If title matches click on button for same element.
                  System.out.println("Button Add basket clicked");
               break; //Break out of iteration.
            }
       }
```

The issue, as it seems, majorly floats around the element being fetched as a collection i.e. . This element does not have a CHILD  as per your xml. To fetch the  element , you need to fetch the parent of  i.e. . From this parent, you can search for the child Add to Basket. Let me know, if this inference make sense. Thanks!!!

**Update: 24 Jun'16 21:00**
I favor a more generic way of finding your "parent" element also (though you might differ). For your issue, do confirm that your 'Add to Basket' element falls under /a/span (in all pages) and has the className as 'js-info-pop-up'. Any deviations might affect the xPath, as it is relative to the currentElement

```
  //List products that have class-cf
  List<WebElement> listProduct = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div/div[@class='accordion-content cf']/div[@class='cf']"));

  for(WebElement eachElem:listProduct)
     {   
      System.out.println("Searching for the exact element:");
      if ( eachElem.getText().contains(TicketName))
          {
           //Identify the button to click on
           WebElement button = eachElem.findElement(By.xpath(".//a/span[@class='js-info-pop-up']"));
           Thread.sleep(500);
           button.click();
           break; //Break out of iteration.    
          }        
     }
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Well, the I got the right element selected but clicking the [Add to basket] button differs from one page to another. The  By.xpath(".//span[@class='js-info-pop-up']")); works for one page but not on other pages. Any different xpath expression I should be trying?

Comment: Can you post your code on how you are able to get the right element? Probably, it is missing something causing differences between pages.

Comment: please see my latest code piece. The issue is the [Add  to basket] button doesn't work for some pages. I need to find a generic xpath to use. Could you suggest any?. Thanks.

Comment: Your code looks good. But please ensure, that all pages has the same element structure - as xPath is relative, and any changes to element struc will not give expected results. Made some changes to code, for a more generic search.